# Automatically change the Outcome of a Task [How To?]

Tags: 2007, workflow, sharepoint-designer, tasks

**Here is my situation:**

I am working on a **workflow** `(in SharePoint Designer)` that is triggered when a new task is created. In some cases, I need to automatically complete a task via my workflow.

To complete the task, the **Outcome** property must me set to **Complete**.

**My Problem:**

I can't access the `Outcome` property in SharePoint designer.

**Is there a way to complete automatically a task in SharePoint?**

thank you!

Bruno

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you set the % Complete to 100 and the Status to Completed?

Comment: that will not progress the workflow, but rather just change those fields for the Task. I have the same requirement. Looking into VS dev...

Comment: I cannot access the Outcome field in my list anywhere using UI. I can't even see it in the List Columns in Admin.

Answer (score 1):

when you change the % complete and status to complete the workflow still stays paused unless you go into the task and complete it.  Once you do this urge outcome field will change and them the workflow will move forward.  I have the same issue..any ideas?